# pure thread-safe Java class

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am recently reading the book "Java Concurrency in Practice". One example of "safe publish" it gives is to initialize a private int field n during construction, and a later assertion on that field n == "expect value" through a public method could still be failed if it is called from another thread. This makes me feel worried in that, assuming all private fields are initialized only once, do we still have to mark them as volatile or wrap them into ThreadLocal or even use an AtomicReference to get a pure thread safe java class, since these private fields, though not visible outside, definitely could be referenced by the method(s) called by other threads.

EDIT: Just to be clear - the assertion is failed because the calling thread sees a stale value of n, even though it has been set during construction. This is a clearly a memory-visibility issue. Problem is whether synchronizing on n is worthy of the overhead after all, since it is only initialized once, and as a private field, author can make sure it won't be changed again.

Comment: I would think that the assertion would always fail if you put the value in a `ThreadLocal` in one thread and run the assertion in a different one.

Comment: if I set val n = new ThreadLocal[Integer] (def initialValue = new Integer(10)) as a static variable, calling n.get() by any threads afterwards would always yield the up-to-date value, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific case is properly documented in the [JSR 133: Java Memory Model and Thread
Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/memory_model-1.0-pfd-spec-oth-JSpec/). It even has a dedicated code sample page 14 section 3.5 *Final Fields* that exactly match your question.

To summarize:

- *A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object’s final fields.*
- There is no guarantee for non final fields

It means that you have to make sure that an happens-before occurs between your object creation in a thread and its usage in another thread. You can use synchronized, volatile or any other mean to enforce an happens-before.

Since you say in another comment that the field is only set during construction, I would make it... final. Also, such shared objects between threads could suggest some design smell; I would review my design to make sure that I am not creating an overly complex, tightly coupled, hard to debug system.

Comment: yep, I just realized that an effectively immutable object should not need any synchronization after all. My concern only applies to the non final primitive.

Comment: Although share objects in multiple threads does not look like a problem to me, for example in a Lucene application, there is a final private val indexReader, and each search (which is essentially a different thread) would need to call the method that depends on indexReader to get the results.

Comment: I am not sure understand your comment or your initial _Marking private field as "final" is not a solution if it refers to an mutable object._ sentence. If the field is only assigned in the ctor then I can be marked as final. Final only means that the reference is immutable not the object pointed by the reference. You will also find this sentence in JSR 133: _will always see the correctly constructed version of that object’s final fields. It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are._

Comment: I was __not__ under the impression that the final field visibility after ctor is done is guaranteed by the Java memory model. A field even if it is marked as final, the object it refers to, as long as itself is not immutable, can still change its internal state, so I thought it is not a solution. I will remove that comment from my original question.

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are never used outside the class, wrapping their usages with synchronized blocks or inside synchronized functions, two threads won't concurrently modify these fields.

`volatile` keyword is just a part of thread safety. It only makes the value of a field never be cached, always read from memory. Take this example.

```
private int myPrivateField = 0;

void someFunction() {
    while(myPrivateField ==0) {
    }
}

void otherFunction() {
    myPrivateField = 1;
}
```

If `someFunction()` is called from one thread and it's running for a while,
when you call `otherFunction()` the value of `myPrivateField` will not be
"updated" inside `someFunction`, it was cached to 0 as an otimization.

Making `myPrivateField` as volatile, the value will always be the one
in memory.

For the example, there won't be much difference for the functions be
synchronized, but without synchronization, you can read a value in an
inconsistent state.

Comment: I know I can do that. problem is if I know for sure the field value is only initialized once, isn't using synchronize an overkill, as there will always be overhead whenever synchronization is used? All I want is to make sure after initialization, the values of these fields are made visible to all threads, and after that, since I know their value wont be changed again (they are private, so as the author, I can make sure that's what will happen), no synchronization is needed at all.

Comment: The reference to the object will not change, but the object fields can change. Is that the problem?

Comment: The object the __private__ field references is only set once during class construction, and wont change afterwards. Marking this field as volatile will help the first time a second thread calling a method that depends on the value of this field, but is a waste after that (since it is not going to be changed any more).

Comment: depends on whether synchronization of assertion would guarantee the most up-to-date visibility of n to all threads, which I doubt about it... But anyway even if it works, that still does not help answer my question. I guess I need to ask in a different way: is there a way to guarantee memory visibility of fields for just once - I don't care if it is a blocking call or not (calling Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE) in constructor, after initialization of private fields would probably work but not really helpful :-).

Comment: I assume all fields are correctly initialized after the constructor is done. Maybe I am wrong. Can you provide some code that shows the problem?

Comment: An example from "Java Concurrency in Practice" (with some revisions): class A { private int n; public A() { this.n = 10 }; public void check() {assert(this.n == 10)} }, calling check() on an instance of class A immediately after its construction by another thread could potentially throw assertion error.

Comment: Seems like that example brings up an issue because it is a non final primitive, as stated by the book: "Safely published effectively immutable objects can be used safely by any
thread without additional synchronization", so I guess my concern should not be worried about :-)

Answer (score 0):

Only final fields are guaranteed to be visible after constructor. Any other field requires some visibility mechanism, such as `synchronized` or `volatile`.

This is not as much of a burden as it seems: if the field is not final, then it can be changed  by another thread while you're reading it. If teh field can be changed, then the last assigned value must be propagated from the writer thread to the reader thread, whether the writer thread called the constructor or a setter.

If the change in this field is not related to any other field in the class, then the field should be `volatile`. If the field is related to other fields in the class, then use `synchronized` or other, more modern locking primitives.

Comment: see my edits, I am asking if the field is only set once during construction, would it worth the overhead to still synchronize it? Note that the field is private, and no set method is exposed through the class interface, nor it could be changed internally.

Comment: if the field is only set during construction, make it `final`?

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the entire question, but it should be pointed out that using `ThreadLocal` is exactly the wrong thing to use if you want to ensure visibility of updated values in all threads. Consider the following code:

```
class Test {
  private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> value = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("From main Thread, value is " + value.get());
    value.set(42);
    System.out.println("Value has been changed");
    Thread t = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("From other Thread, value is " + value.get());
      }
    };
    t.start();
    t.join();
    System.out.println("From main Thread, value is " + value.get());
  }
}
```

This will output the following:

```
From main Thread, value is null
Value has been changed
From other Thread, value is null
From main Thread, value is 42
```

i.e. the other thread doesn't see the updated value. This is because changes to the value of a `ThreadLocal` is, by definition, localized to the thread which changes it.

My personal preference would be to use `AtomicReference`, since this avoids the risk of forgetting to synchronize externally; it also allows things like atomic compare-and-set, which you don't get with a `volatile` variable. However, this may not be a requirement for your particular application.

Comment: if I initialize a ThreadLocal by implementing initialValue = "SomethingExpected", I believe all threads would see the same value assuming set is not used.

Comment: Well, yes, but if you are going to do that you may as well just have the reference as a final field directly, missing out the complication of `ThreadLocal`, since you can't update it in a way that is reliably visible to other threads.

Comment: but in my case, I write the variable just __once__. My wish is to let all threads immediately see the change right after that, so ThreadLocal should be able to satisfy that, though the more appropriate solution, as the answer I already marked in this thread suggests, is I should just mark the variable as final.